# Как переменную int положить в массив char в С++?

Tags: c++

Как переменную int положить в массив char в С++.

Comment: В текстовом виде или в бинарном? Может в шифрованом?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Вопрос очень простой но у меня все таки время отнял по этому решил написать тут ответ :3

Есть переменная(int i) которую мы хотим положить в строковый массив (char stroka[255]).

Для этого нам потребуется дополнительный массив (char dop[255]).

```
int i = 123;
char dop[255];
sprintf (dop, "%d", i); // кладем переменную в массив 
strcat(stroka,dop); // приращиваем к доп. массив к основному строк. массиву
```

Comment: Ну и почему нельзя писать `sprintf`'ом прямо в `stroka`? И если это C++, то почему не воспользоваться `to_string()`?

Comment: кхм... а что сразу мешало сделать это без доп строки? Я уже молчу про то, что к с++ не относится

Answer (score 2):

Если уж очень хочется "прирастить" к строке, то это делается, например, как

```
sprintf(s+strlen(s),"%d",i);
```

без дополнительных пересылок. Но надежнее - `sprintf_s` или, если такового нет, обычно есть что-то типа `snprintf`.

Но вообще-то в C++ строка - это `std::string`, а тут все просто:

```
string s = to_string(i);
```

P.S. Если хочется извращений - их есть у меня:

```
ostringstream os;
os << i;
strcat(stroka,os.str().c_str());
```

:)